# Spring Batch- Write to two different file based on condition

Tags: spring-batch

I want to write data to two different files. If my condition is true then write to x file otherwise to y file.

Currently I have a flat file item writer that writes all the data to one file. I want to specify two different files and based on condition data should go to perticular file.

```
<beans:bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <beans:property name="resource">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource" scope="step">
            <beans:constructor-arg value="${process.output.dir}/${output.file.name}_#{jobParameters['run.id']}.${output.file.extension}" type="java.lang.String" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="lineAggregator">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <beans:property name="delimiter" value="|" />
            <beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
                <beans:bean class="com.abc.common.batch.item.file.transform.FormattingFieldExtractorDecorator">
                    <beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
                        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor" >
                            <beans:property name="names" value="${output.field.names}" />
                        </beans:bean>
                    </beans:property>
                    <beans:property name="defaultDateFormat" value="yyyyMMdd" />
                    <beans:property name="defaultDecimalFormat" value="############0.00" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="headerCallback">
        <beans:bean class="com.abc.common.batch.item.file.HeaderWriter">
            <beans:constructor-arg value="${output.column.names}" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="footerCallback">
        <beans:bean class="com.abc.footer.ItemCountFooterCallback" >
            <beans:constructor-arg name="count" ref="itemCount" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Is your condition based on items? Like for example: if item is of type A then write it to fileA, otherwise write it to fileB.

Comment: my condition is based on item's property. if that property is not blank then write to A otherwise to B

Comment: ok thanks. Please see my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html) is the way to go. It uses a `Classifier` to classify items (this is where you would implement your condition) and multiple item writers (each one will write a specific "class" of items).

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriterTests.java).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will also need header and footer callback as well.

Comment: Those can be configured on delegate writers.

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely do this , you can implement a custom item writer  and then based on your conditions you can achieve the task of writing into different files.

But in this case - the condition and handling the file may hamper the performance of your application , you need to be careful with your implementation

Here I am just giving you the layout , you can write the implementation of writing in your file , first write the custom item writer -

```
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter
```

And then implement a custom itemWriterListener - in which using the beforeWrite method - you can set a different resource

```
 public class WriteListener implements ItemWriteListener{

@Autowire
ItemWrite writer;

 public void beforeWrite(List items) {

   condition 1 (){
       writer.setResource(1)
   }

   condition 2 (){
       writer.setResource(2)
   }    
 }

 public void onWriteError(Exception exception, List items) {

    System.out.println("Error occurred when writing items!");
 }

 public void afterWrite(List items) {

 }  

 }
```